# Как сохранить размеры (высоту) textarea после обновления страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, textarea

У меня есть таблица, в которую вносятся изменения. В некоторых ячейках стоит , где они и производятся. 
Я использую этот код: 
http://xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/forms/textarea-autoresize 
для того, чтобы textarea автоматически расширялась при переходе на новую строку, при этом вместе с ней расширяется и сама ячейка. 
Однако, при обновлении страницы, ее размеры становятся прежними (шириной в 1 строку). Из-за этого не видно большую часть содержимого (она спрятана под textarea). 
Подскажите, как можно сохранить высоту textarea (и ячейки) после внесения изменений и обновления страницы?
Может быть, возможно как-то отслеживать текущие размеры textarea и вносить изменения?

Comment: *В некоторых ячейках стоит textarea

Answer (score 0):

Ну из самого простого - подключить вместо textarea-autoresize библиотеку https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize и инициировать ее при загрузке.

Документация тут - http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

Answer (score 0):

Данные о высоте можно хранить в `localStorage` (и обновлять во время ввода текста). 

А при загрузке страницы - запросить оттуда данные.

```
(function(){

let textarea = doc...('textarea');

if( localStorage.getItem("areaheight") ){ /* вместо areaheight - любое название */
  textarea.style.height = localStorage.getItem("areaheight");
}

textarea.addEventListener('input', function(){
  localStorage.setItem( "areaheight", this.offsetHeight );
});

})();
```

Подробнее → https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp